# While loop in "Finding Middle of Linked List"

Tags: while-loop, linked-list, andand

While writing a code for finding the the middle of the linked List. I encounter a problem where I am not able to understand why one one the snipper works while other does not.
Snippet Working

```
        ListNode *slow = head, *fast = head;
        while (fast && fast->next)
            slow = slow->next, fast = fast->next->next;
        return slow;
```

Snippet not working

```
        ListNode *slow = head, *fast = head;
        while (fast->next && fast)
            slow = slow->next, fast = fast->next->next;
        return slow;
```

Now in my understading, since we have a "&&" condition, it'll go inside the loop only when both the conditions are met, yet, the second snippet fails on some test cases.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Talk us through what you’ve done to debug this code and what you’re seeing when you did.

Comment: Well, Here is the question i am attempting https://www.codingninjas.com/codestudio/problems/973250?topList=striver-sde-sheet-problems&utm_source=striver&utm_medium=website
Here, The first snipper is accepted without problem but the second one has errors in some test cases though I feel like both the codes are identical. 
I am trying to understand the difference between both the codes.

Comment: Have you tried running the code on your own machine to see what happens in each case? You might notice what’s going on if you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `&&` is a [short-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) operator, so that the second operand is only evaluated when the first operand evaluates to a truthy value.

The correct code has this:

```
(fast && fast->next)
```

Which means that `fast->next` is only evaluated when `fast` is not a null pointer.

Now take the the other code:

```
(fast->next && fast)
```

Here `fast->next` is evaluated first before having verified that `fast` is not a null pointer. If `fast` **is** a null pointer, this represents an invalid de-referencing and the program will have undefined behaviour.